# How to fetch all the document libraries into a FolderCollection for SharePoint Online C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am trying to get the name of the document libraries of SharePoint online into a FolderCollection using the below code. But it looks like I am not getting the display name of "Documents" which is the default document library, instead I am getting "Shared Documents".

```
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/mSite"))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, sePassword);

            Web site = clientContext.Web;

            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            FolderCollection folderColl = clientContext.Web.Folders;
            clientContext.Load(folderColl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Folder currentFolder = null;

            foreach (Folder fol in folderColl)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fol.Name); // not giving the "Documents"
                if (fol.Name == "Documents") // not executing this block since no "Documents"
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Current Folder: " + currentFolder.Name);
                }
            }

        }
```

I know I can get them as a "list" with the name "Documents", but I need them in a FolderCollection. Is there any way to get the "Documents" instead of "Shared Documents" in the FolderCollection? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you treat document libraries as Folders, then the Document library's name *is* `Shared Documents`, not `Documents`.

`Documents` is merely a "Title" that can be different in different translations. The "Name" on the other hand never changes.

This is the URL of the default Document library. Notice how it says "Shared Documents"

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA/Shared Documents/
```

The URL part of the Folder always matches the Name.